# Unable to access "USBname"

Tags: boot, usb, mount, format, unmount

I have a USB flash drive which *used to contain* Kali Linux and I tried to re-format it in Ubuntu, to use it for other purposes.

Suddenly, an error screen popped up `Unable to access “Kali Live”`. I don't know what to do. This is the error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/asian_rice_ball/Kali Live1: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/asian_rice_ball/Kali Live1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Its on ubuntu actually

Comment: Kali linux IS ON the USB. I made it using ubuntu. I formatted on ubuntu. I opened it on ubuntu. it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I apologize for the inaccuracy. I didn't read the question correctly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MarkYisri True, but the user is on Ubuntu trying to recover a USB flash drive for other uses. This is on topic. What the USB drive contains is not relevant.

Comment: oh, ok. What should I do? I think it has a "iso9660" format.

Comment: I suggested and edit to make it clear and also code tags for the error message to improve readability.

Comment: You probably can do it graphically with Disks: Delete all partitions, create a new partition table and format using the desired file system.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. I'm kind of a newbie here.

Comment: sorry, could you dumb it down? lol

Comment: Now it doesn't even read it...

Comment: 1 make sure you are not booting with the USB--plug it in after Ubuntu is running. 2 in system settings, removable media, make sure auto run of USB is turned off. 3 if USB was formatted in UEFI and you are in Legacy mode 'gparted' and 'disks' programs will not be able to access sometimes unless first 128 bytes are filled with hex '0' (zeros). 4 use 'dd' VERY CAREFULLY to populate first 128 bytes of dusk (aka MBR) if that step needs to be done. 5 Sorry for comment masquerading as an answer but I'm on my phone. 6 Plan B buy new USB stick for 10 bucks (32 GB)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open GParted:
   [image: gparted screenshot]
2. Select the USB stick in the upper right-hand corner
3. Choose the <kbd>Device menu</kbd>
4. Choose <kbd>Create new partition table</kbd>
5. Create a new <kbd>ms-dos</kbd> partition that takes up the whole space of the USB drive.

And that should solve the problem and if it doesn't, the USB stick is broken: throw it away and buy a new one.

Comment: ***Now** it's a good answer!* (and worthy of an upvote!) **:D** Please [edit] the answer and have a look around how I did that...  ;-)

Comment: Don't thank me:go upvote some of my answers!  :D